# How to fetch a single document from firestore with an id from useParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a web application where you can see a list of gymnasts. When you click on the name a gymnast you move to that specific gymnast page with the help off the useParams hook. On that page I want to fetch the relating document from Firestore with the help of that id. Unfortunately I get an error that is probably related to Typescript. I get the following error:

[image]

How can I make the following code work?

```
export const GymnastPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  
  const docRef = doc(db, "GymnastsByCoach", user.uid, "Gymnasts", id)
  
  onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data(), doc.id)
  });
  
  return()
};
```

The code works when I hardcode the Id of the document instead of taking id from useParams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `useParams` is asynchronously setting the `id` in the state. In that case, you'll have to use `useEffect` to make your code respond to when the `id` is set:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const docRef = doc(db, "GymnastsByCoach", user.uid, "Gymnasts", id)
  
  onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data(), doc.id)
  });
}, [id]);
```

Now the code to load from Firestore will run once the `id` value gets set.